# Integrate Hospital Bed Planning (PAS - Patient Admission Scheduling)) with my web application

Tags: optaplanner

I have a web application developed using spring and deployed in jboss eap server.

One of the function is booking bed for patient. 
My question is how to integrate this to my application. I saw in documents about rest call etc but need to know in detail. Which one to use the standlaone or web application of optaplanner

Answer (score 0):

If you're already running on EAP+Spring+JVM, then just use embedded OptaPlanner. Add the `optaplanner-core` dependency and take a look at the getting started tutorial (chapter 2 in the reference manual).

Comment: Thanks Geoff,Did u mean jboss EAP 6 has embedded PtaPlanner?? chapter 2 of which document